# Decompressing Nuxt js files from Developer Tools

Tags: javascript, nuxt.js, visual-web-developer

Is there a way to see other websites Nuxt.js files from the developer tools. For instance, I'm curious how some websites do their animations in JS and I want to look at it but it all seems to be compressed.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

no way , You can only guess by experience, because it is compressed through random token

nuxt it is use Webpack for compressed tool